# search MVC javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

so I have this javascript... It searches data in my view. It works great but only when you press the "FIND/(hledat)" button but I need it to work when I press enter...

thanks for any idea

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").click(function () {
        var hledat = $("input[name='table_search']").val();
        $("input[name='filter']").val(hledat);
        var $create = $('#Create');
        location.href = '@(@Url.Action("Create", "Request"))' + "?filter=" + hledat;
    });
});
```

Comment: Try to tie onto the submit even of the form.. https://api.jquery.com/submit/ in jQuery because you're already using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract your logic in function and use it on multiple events:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").click(function () {
        search();
    });

    function handleEnterSearch(e){
        var key=e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (key==13){
            search();
        }
    }

    function search() {
        var hledat = $("input[name='table_search']").val();
        $("input[name='filter']").val(hledat);
        var $create = $('#Create');
        location.href = '@(@Url.Action("Create", "Request"))' + "?filter=" + hledat;
    }
});
```